# difference between "despite" and "notwithstanding"

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Translator changed my sentence from;

"our verbal warnings, notifications and instructions notwithstanding, he failed to provide..."

to

"despite our verbal warnings, notifications and instructions, he failed to provide..."

Is there a difference between two ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no difference in meaning.

Notwithstanding and despite imply "in spite of" and have been used in the sentences as prepositions. The only difference is that the use of notwithstanding is formal.  Moreover, notwithstanding can also be used as an adverb such as He doesn't want me there, but I am going, notwithstanding.